# How to link to a page on the current domain without writing the full URL

Tags: html, url, hyperlink

Let's say the current URL is `example.com/test/example`

and let's say I want to link to `example.com/test/example/another`

`<a href="/another">` links me to `example.com/another`

How can I link to `example.com/test/example/another` without having to put the full URL in the `a` tag?

Comment: This question [omit domain name for base tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92146/) and these links [base URL and fallback ULR](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/urls-and-fetching.html#document-base-url) or [HTML 5.1 2nd edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/infrastructure.html#dynamic-changes-to-base-urls) might be of use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<a href="another">
```

should do it.

EDIT: My bad, it actually is:

```
<a href="./another">
```

Comment: Yes. I don't know how I forgot this.

Comment: actually, no, likning to "another" from "example.com/test/example" would attempt to go to "example.com/test/another". To get to "example.com/test/example/another", you'd have to link to "./another"

Comment: I see. Are there other variations of this that link to different paths?

Comment: Well, `../another` from `example.com/test/example` goes to `example.com/another`

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest using root-relative paths, if you'd prefer not to use absolute paths:

```
<a href="/test/example/another">Link text</a>
```

Otherwise, for relative paths, [itdoesntwork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9055396/82548)'s answer covers the use-case.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this: `href="another"`